# Команда redo в emacs?

Tags: emacs, hotkeys

В редакторе Emacs на команду `undo` есть несколько hotkeys, в частности:
`C-/`, `C-x u`, `C-_`

Как можно запустить команду `redo` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В emacs нет команды `redo` (в смысле, той redo о которой Вы спрашиваете).
Однако, желаемый результат (отмена предыдущих `undo`) легко достигается той же командой `undo`.

Если вы что-то делали (вводили текст, удаляли слова, вставляли их в другое место, опять вводили текст), решили отменить несколько последних действий, т.е. сделали несколько `undo` (например, набирая `C-/`) и поняли, что сделали лишние `undo`, то просто сдайте что-то, не меняющее текст, скажем, нажмите стелку вправо (`C-f`) и опять введите `undo` (`C-/`).

Теперь, новые `undo` будут отменять действия предыдущих `undo` (т.е. по сути это и будет искомое Вами redo).

Описание во встроенной документации несколько "зарыто" (находится в разделе -- *20 Commands for Fixing Typos*).
Приведу здесь цитату оттуда:

> To begin to undo, type `C-/` (or its aliases, `C-_` or `C-x u`)(1).
>   This undoes the most recent change in the buffer, and moves point back
>   to where it was before that change.
>
> Consecutive repetitions of `C-/` (or its aliases) undo earlier and
>   earlier changes in the current buffer.  If all the recorded changes
>   have already been undone, the undo command signals an error.
>
> Any command other than an undo command breaks the sequence of undo
>   commands.  Starting from that moment, the entire sequence of undo
>   commands that you have just performed are themselves placed into the
>   undo record, as a single set of changes.  Therefore, to re-apply
>   changes you have undone, type `C-f` or any other command that
>   harmlessly breaks the sequence of undoing; then type `C-/` to undo the
>   undo command.
>
> On the other hand, if you want to resume undoing, without redoing
>   previous undo commands, use `M-x undo-only`.  This is like `undo`, but
>   will not redo changes you have just undone.

Далее там даются разные полезные, относящиеся к undo сведения.

И в любом случае, советую почитать всю эту замечательную документацию (введите `C-h r` и читайте прямо в emacs в формате info).

Comment: Похоже, что в Emacs 28 команда Redo будет сделана по уму: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527142/how-do-you-redo-changes-after-undo-with-emacs#60163018

Answer (score 1):

по аналогии
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'undo)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, т.е. на C-z поцепить undo?  ... Т.е. чтобы сделать redo, нужно сделать отмену undo?

Comment: по-аналогии! я просто не помню, что стоит на 'redo, можно написать что_угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Поставь пакет [undo-tree](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/undo-tree.html), там все более чем наглядно. Можно "перемещаться" по разным веткам undo/redo, что бывает очень полезно.

Answer (score 1):

C-/ undo. C-g C-/ redo. Здесь описано детальней https://stackoverflow.com/a/18383455/2059589